# Python imshow cmap for Binary data

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, imshow

I have a binary dataframe. I want to display and stored it in PDF using imshow. I want to prescribe a customized color, say Green for True and Red for False.
My code:

```
df = 
       A         B          C         D          E            F
0     True       True       True     True        True        True
1     True       True       True     True        True        True
2     True      False      False     True        True        True
3     True       True       True     True        True        True
4     True       True       True     True        True        True
5    True       True       True     True        True        True
6   False      False       True    False       False       False
7    True       True       True     True        True        True

plt.imshow(df,interpolate='none',cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Expected plot:

In the above plot, Green for white and Red for black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmap = 'gray' mean explicitly use the white/black gradient.

You can make your own map

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmp=ListedColormap(['red','green'])
```

then call this map in imshow

```
plt.imshow(df,cmap=cmp)
plt.show()
```

P.S. You can find all the colors of the maps you can use here https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html